# Initializing custom type

Tags: go

Can someone help me to understand the following situation?

Having a custom type

```
type Foo string
```

This construction works:

```
var foo Foo = "foo"
fmt.Printf("\n%s", foo)
```

And this:

```
var bar = "bar"
var foo Foo = bar
fmt.Printf("\n%s", foo)
```

Throws a `cannot use bar (variable of type string) as type Foo in variable declaration.` What are the differences and how can I initialize this type properly?
Thanks

Comment: The difference is that "foo" is an **untyped** constant value which can take the type of Foo, and bar is a **typed** variable, a variable of type string and it cannot automatically take the type string, only via explicit type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me correct this

```golang
var bar = "bar"
var foo Foo = Foo(bar)
fmt.Printf("\n%s", foo)
```

or just

```golang
var foo = Foo(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

The last one doesn't work because Go has strong type check; also if `Foo` has `string` as base type, it's not a `string`.

For that reason you cannot assign a string to it.

to achieve what you want you have to do casting

```golang
func main() {
    var a = "hello"
    var b Foo
    b = Foo(a)
    fmt.Println("b:", b)
}
```